# How to migrate custom Wix extension from 3 to 4

Tags: wix, wix4

I have a custom WiX extension (an extension for WiX itself).

https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/tree/master/VisioWixExtension

This one is for building Office (Visio) related installations.

It has a custom table, scheduled actions, exec actions, etc. Lots of stuff.

I would really appreciate some pointers on how to migrate it to v4.
A link to some document would be perfect. If there is no such document, would appreciate any other source of information (such as example of migrated extension). What should I look at in the first place, i.e. where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at WiX's extensions. I'd start with a simpler one, like Firewall: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/tree/develop/src/ext/Firewall

Comment: I see. Thank you, now doing that :) Looks like almost EVERYTHING is changed in version 4, including the framework, lol. Have to fix every single file out of 50 :/

Comment: Got a question - the extension uses BinderExtension. I have not found the built-in extensions that use it somehow? Maybe it should not be used, but something else. What the extension needs to do: load the content of some installer file, with which it is associated, and depending on that content, generate some additional entries to installer table. It should be in the binder, or? In v.3 it was using `DatabaseFinalize(Output output)` hook. What should be used in v.4?

Comment: https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/blob/2871c0584ab97af2f8cdf1e68bbb8ee1fd58824a/VisioWixExtension/wixext/VisioBinderExtension.cs#L17

Comment: Take a look at `BaseWindowsInstallerBackendBinderExtension`.